# Las etiquetas ya pueden tener 35 caracteres

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Hace un par de días, [Shog9 anunció](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/209901) que las etiquetas pasan a tener un nuevo límite de longitud.

A partir de ahora, **las etiquetas pueden tener un máximo de 35 caracteres**.

Utilizad este nuevo poder sabiamente :)

<sub>Esto implica que la página de ayuda el privilegio de [Creación de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) debe modificar *No deben tener más de 25 caracteres* por *No deben tener más de 35 caracteres*.</sub>

Comment: creo que no se podia crear una etiqueta con espaciados, ahora ya se puede?

Comment: @x-rw no, no se puede. Tal y como explica [Creación de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags): _Deben utilizar el conjunto de caracteres a-z áéíóúüñ 0-9 + # - ._